# Laravel service provider class not found in forked vender

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.4

I was developing with a repo that worked fine in Laravel. When I forked the repo, I now get this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Class 'DevIT\Hasoffers\Laravel\Providers\HasoffersServiceProvider' not found
```

I tried commenting out the provider line in `app.php`, then ran these, and afterward uncommented the line but these didn't help:

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan optimize
```

Here is the config for that in composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "devit/hasoffers-php-client": "dev-master",
    "devit/hasoffers-laravel-client": "dev-master"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "devit/hasoffers-php-client",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/ecomevo/hasoffers-php.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "devit/hasoffers-laravel-client",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/ecomevo/hasoffers-laravel.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            }
        }
    }
],
```

If I navigate to the vendor dir, the package is there and composer claims it brought it in during latest update.

What have I gotten wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your composer file is using [`package` repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2), which will not read the `composer.json` file of the packages being pulled in. Since the PSR-4 autoloading is defined in those `composer.json` files, it is not being setup, and your class is not being found.

You could add the autoload functionality to your packages definition, but your best bet would be to use the [`vcs` repository type](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs), so that their `composer.json` files will be respected.

Your composer file should look something like:

```
"require": {
    "devit/hasoffers-php-client": "dev-master",
    "devit/hasoffers-laravel-client": "dev-master"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/ecomevo/hasoffers-php"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/ecomevo/hasoffers-laravel"
    }
],
```

Since you have already pulled these packages in with a previous method, you may need to clear your composer cache before doing a composer update:

```
composer clearcache
composer update devit/hasoffers-php-client
composer update devit/hasoffers-laravel-client
```